# Rails mailer attachment with password protection +rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attachment, pdfkit, mailer

Not sure if I am on right track or not but I was searching for a way where I can make the attachment(PDF that is created by [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit)) password-protected, though I couldn't find any satisfactory solution for this issue.

Another approach for making the pdf with the password is to make changes to how it was being created, but again, there are not so many things on the web to create the PDF with the password with [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit)

Hope anyone can show some light on the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got what I was looking for,

https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#password-protection-experimental

By doing some little changes in this method, it turned out to be what I was expecting it to be.

There'll be for sure any better solution for this but have found this one as of now, and hope it will be helpful for others.

```
compressed_filestream = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer(::StringIO.new(''), Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new(PASSWORD_WHICH_WE_WANT_TO_SET)) do |zos|
  zos.put_next_entry FILE_NAME
  zos.print FILE_PATH.EXTENSION
end
compressed_filestream.rewind
```